# Two-dimensional bisection method in Python?

Tags: python, bisection

I am looking for an extension of the `optimize.bisect` function in Python, some code that allows me to solve a system of two couple self-consistent equations, i.e. `y= f(x,y)` and `x= g(x,y)`. I was looking for a kind of two dimensional bisection method, but I doesn't mind to use other possibilities if it works fine.

Comment: can you give an example

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your problem, you want to find the root of the following function

```
def fun(x):
    return [f(x[0], x[1]) - x[1],
            g(x[0], x[1]) - x[0]]
```

where `x[0]` corresponds to `x` in your definition and `x[1]` corresponds to `y`.
You can solve this by using e.g. [scipy.optimize.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root)

```
from scipy import optimize
solution = optimize.root(fun, [0, 0])
```

Here `[0, 0]` is the initial guess for the root. However, the choice of the proper algorithm highly depends on your problem.